# how to save decimal value in flat table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

How to properly save decimal data in magento flat table ?

I created table via magento install script:

```
    mysql> describe my_geo_table;

    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | entity_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

     ...

    | Longitude   | decimal(10,0)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | Latitude    | decimal(10,0)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

in my test script, I try to save model:

```
    $address = Mage::getModel('Mymodule/my_geo_table')
                            ->setData(...)
                            ->setLatitude(53.5586509)
                            ->setLongitude(9.6469548)
                            ->save();
```

It saves without error, but when i see mysql table contents, these values are differs :

```
    +-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
    | entity_id | ...       |Longitude | Latitude |
    +-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
    |         1 | ...       |        54 |       10 |
    +-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

How to save decimal value in magento table correctly ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Marius, figured out how to correctly add decimal columns for longitude and latitude. Maybe one can find it useful:

```
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn('my_geo_table', 'longitude', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
            'scale'     => 7,
            'precision' => 10,
            'nullable' => false,
            'comment' => 'Longitude'
        ));

    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn('my_geo_table', 'latitude', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
            'scale'     => 7,
            'precision' => 9,
            'nullable' => false,
            'comment'   => 'Latitude'
    ));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your latitude column (and longitude) are of type `decimal(10,0)`.
This means you can save up to 10 digits in it and none of them are decimals.

Since you want to save 7 decimal digits and the max longitude possible is 180 and the max latitude is 90 you should make your columns look like this:

```
| Longitude   | decimal(10,7)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Latitude    | decimal(9,7)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```